# This python for loop and if statement are acting strange

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I was solving a problem where I needed to write a code like following:

```
c = [0,0,1,0,0,1,0]
for i in range(7):
    if(i<7-2 and c[i+2] == 0):
        i += 1
    print(i)
```

I expected output like this:

```
0
2
3
5
6
```

But I am getting this:

```
0
2
3
3
5
5
6
```

But with same logic/code in C it is working fine...

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int c[] = {0,0,1,0,0,1,0};
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<7;i++){
        if(i<7-2 && c[i+2] == 0){
            i++;
        }
        printf("%d\n",i);
    }
}
```

What is the reason(s) or what am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `for i in range(7)` loop in python behaves as `for i in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]`. `i` is the values in that list, rather than an index being incremented. Thus, your `i += 1` doesn't do what you think it does.

You could use a while loop to get the same behavior as the c for loop, but there's probably a more pythonic way to write it.

```
i = 0
while i < 7:
   if(i<7-2 and c[i+2] == 0):
        i += 1
   print(i)
   i+=1
```

Answer (score 1):

The for-in loop just assigns every member of the range to `i` in it's turn, it does not increment `i`. Thus, any modification you make to `i` is lost at the end of the loop's current iteration.

You can get the desired behavior with a `while` loop, but you'd have to increment `i` yourself:

```
i = 0
while i < 7:
    if(i<7-2 and c[i+2] == 0):
        i += 1
    print(i)
    i += 1
```